# Filter array depending on other table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to filter values from an array. The information, which values should be kept, are in another table.

```
table_a                        table_b
___________________            ___________
| id | values     |            | keyword |
-------------------            -----------
| 1  | [a, b, c]  |            |    b    |
| 2  | [d, e, f]  |            |    e    |
| 3  | [a, g]     |            |    f    |
-------------------            -----------
```

I expect the following output:

```
output
________________________
| id | filtered_values | 
------------------------
| 1  | [b]             | 
| 2  | [e, f]          |
| 3  | []              |
------------------------
```

At the moment, I am using following query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  array_intersect(ta.values, tb.filter_keywords) AS filtered_values -- brickhouse UDF
FROM
  table_a ta
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
    collect_set(keyword) as filter_keywords
  FROM (
    SELECT
      "dummy" as grouping_dummy,
      keyword
    FROM
      table_b
  ) tmp
  GROUP BY
    grouping_dummy
)
```

table_a has a couple million rows, table_b contains less than 1000 rows.
I guess the cross join is the bottleneck, because it uses only one reducer.

Is there any way to optimize this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a different assumption.

The reducer is needed in order to generate `filter_keywords`, not for the `CROSS JOIN` which is a map side operation.
So no problem here.

My guess is that the performance penalty comes from the use of `array_intersect` with an array of 1000 elements, therefor the solution would be avoiding it.

P.s.
There is no need for `grouping_dummy`.
You don't need to use `GROUP BY` in order to use aggregate functions.

```
select      a.id
           ,collect_list (case when b.keyword is not null then a.val end)  as vals


from       (select  a.id
                   ,e.val

            from    table_a a

                        lateral view outer 

                            explode (a.vals) e as val
            ) a

            left join   table_b b

            on          b.keyword   =
                        a.val

group by    a.id
```

---

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   vals    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | ["b"]     |
|  2 | ["e","f"] |
|  3 | []        |
+----+-----------+
```